# ListView with custom adapter state persistence

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-adapter

I have a list view with custom adapter. The custom adater is just TextView and 2 ImageButtons.
When the ImageButton is clicked I want its image to toggle. This works however, when I scroll down some random items are also toggled.

So I thought it's related to relativeness of items positions on the screen. So I assigned a tag to each ImageButton that corresponds to its position in the list view. Then I use the following code to correctly select necessary item:

```
    int firstVisiblePos = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    int viewPos = 0;
    int position = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
    Toast.makeText(this, v.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    for (int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        viewPos = firstVisiblePos + i;
        if (viewPos == position) {              
            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) listView.getChildAt(position);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Yet I still experience the same behaviour. 
Any help is appreciated.

UPD:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<String> data;
private Activity myActivity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> data) {
    this.myActivity = activity;
    this.data = data;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) myActivity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    }

    TextView proverb = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    proverb.setText(data.get(position));
    proverb.setTextSize(android.util.TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
    proverb.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf, 1);
    ImageButton favBtn = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_favorite);
    if(MainActivity.favorites.contains(data.get(position))){
        // favorite, set fav icon
        favBtn.setImageDrawable(myActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav));         
    }       
    favBtn.setTag(position);
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: post your getView() method of your Custom Adapter.

Comment: From getView() its not clear, so post your full Adapter class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

Create a Model first to store the value and check for Favurite

```
public class Data {

private String value;
private boolean favurite;

public Data(String value,boolean favurite){
    this.value=value;
    this.favurite=favurite;
}
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
public boolean isFavurite() {
    return favurite;
}
public void setFavurite(boolean favurite) {
    this.favurite = favurite;
}
```

}

Then instead of creating `ArrayList<String>` change it to `ArrayList<Data>` in Your `Activity`

```
ArrayList<Data> list=new ArrayList<Data>();
        list.add(new Data("value1", false));
        list.add(new Data("value2", false));
```

and pass it to CustomAdapter class

**I changed your adapter class to make working**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Data> data;
    private Activity myActivity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Data> data) {
        this.myActivity = activity;
        this.data = data;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) myActivity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    }
    final Data d=data.get(position);
    TextView proverb = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    proverb.setText(d.getValue());
    proverb.setTextSize(android.util.TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
    proverb.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf, 1);
    final ImageButton favBtn = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_favorite);

    if(d.isFavurite())
        favBtn.setImageDrawable(myActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav));    
    else
        favBtn.setImageDrawable(myActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Non_fav));

    favBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            d.setFavurite(true);
            favBtn.setImageDrawable(myActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav));    
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: I introduced changes suggested by you. However, I did not create a new Data class. It works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your list items are reused as the user scrolls through the listview. Thus, you have to rebuild the list item based on the data each time. It looks like you are changing the image if the item is a favorite, but you are not changing it back if it is not a favorite.

try changing

```
if(MainActivity.favorites.contains(data.get(position))){
    // favorite, set fav icon
    favBtn.setImageDrawable(myActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav));         
}
```

to

```
if(MainActivity.favorites.contains(data.get(position))){
    // favorite, set fav icon
    favBtn.setImageDrawable(myActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav));         
} else {
    // not favorite, set default icon
    favBtn.setImageDrawable(myActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.notfav));
}
```

I am assuming that when you click on the image button it adds `data.get(position)` to `MainActivity.favorites` and removes it when you click it again.

Comment: It solves the original problem, but now I get null pointer exceptions. I got fully working solution combining your answer and Amit Gupta's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing,,, do not check for the nullity of convertView, and code directly one by one,,,like this

```
     @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);


    TextView proverb = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    proverb.setText(data.get(position));
    proverb.setTextSize(android.util.TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
    proverb.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf, 1);
    ImageButton favBtn = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_favorite);
    if(MainActivity.favorites.contains(data.get(position))){
        // favorite, set fav icon
        favBtn.setImageDrawable(myActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav));         
    }       
    favBtn.setTag(position);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Actually it was found from my side,,,, when we inflate view every time the scrolling toggling issue in listview will be solved